# How can you convert LF's to CRLF in a text file using a vbscript?

Tags: csv, vbscript, newline, line-endings

I have a CSV file that gets generated by a Mac program (unfortunately, with little encoding flexibility) which writes LFs at the end of lines. Then a vbscript reads this file like so:

```
Set objTextFile = fso.OpenTextFile("the_file.csv", 1)
lineItemString = objTextFile.Readline
```

However, since it is looking for CRLF at the end of the lines, `lineItemString` contains the text of the entire file. Since this is a daily procedure, I'd like not to have to add an interim step of using some utility program that properly converts all the line endings to CRLF.

Is there a way to avoid this by doing this conversion from within my vbscript?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This will replace each LF in a string with CRLF:

```
Replace(str, vbLf, vbCrLf)
```

Depending on how you want to process the file it might be easier to just read the entire file and split the content by `vbLf`, though.

```
Set objTextFile = fso.OpenTextFile("the_file.csv", 1)
For Each line In Split(objTextFile.ReadAll, vbLf)
  ' do stuff
Next
```

Comment: Excellent advice, I think I will end up doing this. I accepted Steven's answer because he answered first. Voted this up though! Thanks!

Comment: @AndyPerlitch this should be the accepted answer, the other answer was deleted as it likely due to being a link only answer.